# Issue with the Google Internet Authority G2 certificate

Tags: windows, certificate, ca

I'm encountering an issue accessing the google.com website. When trying to access this page, every web browser on my Windows 10 system displays the error message:

NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
Subject: *.google.com
Issuer: Google Internet Authority G2 v.14.5.1.4
Expires on: July 28, 2023
Current date: August 23, 2023

I understand that this certificate has indeed expired. Interestingly, on another one of my PCs, when accessing google.com, the GTS CA 1C3 certificate is utilized. I also have the GTS CA 1C3 certificate installed on the problematic PC, but for some reason, it's not being utilized, and the system continues to access the site using the expired Google Internet Authority G2 certificate. I've even attempted to remove the Google Internet Authority G2 certificate using the MMC, but after restarting the PC, the certificate is always reinstated.[certificates in MMC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7RGo.png)

I would need advice on how to set the correct certificate for accessing google.com in the system.

Comment: This is not about programming or development and thus offtopic, but is "my" system really yours, i.e. you bought it yourself, or is it assigned to you by an employer or other organization? If the latter it may have interception software, especially given a friendlyname saying Fiddler. Similarly if it is using some entity's network connection. That cert is definitely not a real Google cert; they stopped using "Google Internet Authority G2" several years ago, and even before then it did not any have v.14.5.1.4 in the name and it was not self-signed but issued by GeoTrust Global CA.